# How peripherals are initialised in Embedded Linux

Tags: embedded-linux

I am a newbie to Embedded Linux. I am working on IMX6UL Evaluation kit and working through the Yocto build process.
I apologize if my questions are very basic, I am trying to understand Linux bootup and Initialisation process.

I have understood the device tree where peripherals are assigned.
But I don't understand where they are initialized, like LCD, SPI, I2C.

As my background is bare metal, I understand it has to be initialized somewhere. But where this is done in Linux. I don't understand.

Can someone please point me out with some examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initialization for any device is done in the probe call of it's driver. The "compatible" property from the device tree is used to match against the [of_match_table](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/iio/adc/vf610_adc.c#n971) and [probe](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/iio/adc/vf610_adc.c#n801) is called first. Device tree node for the driver example is [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/boot/dts/vfxxx.dtsi#n276).

Edit: Should have added that, technically exactly probe won't be the first to be called. There is the helper macro module_platform_driver which is basically used when module_init/exit don't do anything special.